# How do I check which radio button is selected when there are multiple radio buttons with the same name? (using jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<form class="responses">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="0">False</input>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="1">True</input>
</form>
```

Have tried:

```
$('[name="choice"]').is(':checked'))
```

If either is checked it returns true, if neither is checked returns false, but I need to see which one is checked.

I am creating choices dynamically, and am not giving each an ID.

Comment: `$('form.responses')[0].choice.value`

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, this works, I'm trying to understand it, I can't figure out what the [0] is.  I thought it might be the index of something, but doesn't look like it is.

Comment: jquery returns an array-like object, so you want to access the first item ... without jquery, you can do `document.querySelector('form.responses').choice.value` instead

Comment: if you give the form an id="fred" for example, even easier ... `document.forms.fred.choice.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will give the value of the checked radio button. If nothig is checked it will give undefined. Put this snippet inside a function and call the function on checking radio button

```
$("input[name='choice']:checked").val()
```

Answer (score 1):

With the following code you will get the DOM of the checked radio element

`$("[name=choice]:checked")`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the selected value use

```
$("input:radio[name='choice']:checked").val();
```

If you want to know which radio button is selected use

```
var radioButton = $("input:radio[name='choice']");
var selectedIndex = radioButton.index(radioButton.filter(':checked'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are the perfect one , this can be an another approach

HTML :

```
<form class="responses">
 <input type="radio" name="choice" class="my_radio" value="0">False</input>
 <input type="radio" name="choice" class="my_radio" value="1">True</input>
</form>
```

JQUERY:

```
 $('.my_radio').click(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('input[name=choice]:checked', '#myForm').val()
```

Script:

```
$( "#myForm input" ).on( "change", function() {
  $( "#log" ).html( $( "input[name=choice]:checked" ).val() + " is checked!" );
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="0">False</input>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="1">True</input>
</form>
<div id="log"></div>
```

```js
$( "#myForm input" ).on( "change", function() {
  $( "#log" ).html( $( "input[name=choice]:checked" ).val() + " is checked!" );
});
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <form id="myForm">
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="0">False</input>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="1">True</input>
        </form>
        <div id="log"></div>
```